# Как вытащить значение из запроса Axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, es2016

Всем привет.
Есть такой код:
(Обратить внимание на HTML класс 'symbolTicket"')

```js
<template>

  <div class="chart">

    <span class="symbolTicket">
      {{getTicket()}}
    </span>

    <div class="chartContent">

    </div>
    <!--   <div class="chartContent">  end   -->

  </div>
  <!--   <div class="chart">   end   -->

</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios';

export default{

  methods: {

    getTicket: function () {

        return axios.get("http://localhost:2000/" , {
          params: {
            foo: 'SELECT * FROM eur_usd WHERE primary_key = 2;'
          }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data.ticket);
            return response.data.ticket;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

    },

  },

}

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Мне необходимо каким то образом вытащить значение из запроса.
Что только не пробовал - ниче не помагает.

P.S. Результат работы текущего(не работающего) решения можно увидеть на скрине.
C верху можно увидеть какое значение вернулось.(обьект вместо данных)
С низу в консоли лог - видим, что сам ответ рабочий(без ошибок.)
Именно эти данные и необходимо вывести внутри тега.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понял что требуется? )
(код же приаттачен к посту.)

Comment: 1. Зачем вы передаёте запрос к БД?  2.  Перепишите метод так:  `getTicket () { return axios.get("http://localhost:2000/" , { params: {foo: 'SELECT * FROM eur_usd WHERE primary_key = 2;'}});`.

Comment: Автор прочитай пожалуйста статью о Промисах в JS: https://learn.javascript.ru/promise . Судя по всему у вас нет понимания, что это такое и как работает.

Comment: >> 1. Зачем вы передаёте запрос к БД?
Это мой пилотный личный проект - пока на стадии обучения в плане серверной разработки.
Не нашел варианта рабочего как с помощью pg-promise принимать параметры - все время ошибки синтаксические вылазят.
Пока что стоит задача почувствовать как вообще все это работает.

Comment: я читал статью о промисах и даже их использовал - но сдесь же метод Axiosa а не чистый промис - поэтому это меня не много ввело в заблуждение.

Comment: @MikeKharkov Axios промис и возвращает после завершения запроса. С гитхаба axios'а: Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод getTicket возвращает Promise. Т.е. вызывая функцию, делается ajax запрос к серверу, он занимает некоторое время. Функция же выполняется моментально.
По идее надо сделать вот так:
В getTicket

```
return axios.get(url, params)
```

А при вызове getTicket вот так:

```
getTicket().then(...).catch(...)
```

Comment: Или другой вариант, логику обработки полностью перенести в getTicket, тогда проблем вообще не будет и не надо будет из функции ничего возвращать.